# SSIS failure scenario triggered all the time

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, integration

I have a problem with flow in SSIS package.
For increasing the performance I have generally the same logic for importing data from MS Access files into SQL Server Database:

- 1st Task - try to bulk insert data (Table or View - fast load)
- If there was a failure (e.g. constraint violation), the whole bunch of records is passed to next task - normal insert (Table View)
- all problem records are passed to next steps for loggin into flat files (txt)

The problem I face is that even when the first insert went fine, I still reach the failure flow and an empty error log file is created all the time.
In my understanding the process should reach this point only in case there were problems before.

For better understanding I attach image with execution results and there are green ticks up to the end.

Would appreciate any advice for workaround. What I need is to create error log files - only when there was any error with details about the problem.

Thanks!

[image: Wrong flow in SSIS package]

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing the data flow with the control flow to some degree.

The StockExchange - error log will be created as it may receive records from the dataflow.

The way around this could be:

1) Create a temporary error log file to temporary hold failed rows, or zero rows if successful in a temporary location.

2) After the "StockExchange - Get Error Desc" component add a rowcount component and assign to a variable e.g. iErrorCount

3) in your control flow, after the Data flow add two precedence constraints. one with @iErrorCount > 0 and one with @iErrorCount ==0. If it's zero you add a File System Task to delete the temporary log file (has it has zero rows)

4) for the @ErrorCount > 0 path, you add a file System Task to copy the temporary log file to your required location with valid name. And add a file system task to delete the temporary log file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This would be a bit complicated and a lot of redundant manual job - as I have the same pattern repeated for many tables, I would need to have as many variables for row count and adding so many additional tasks there. The way I already thought how to do it - I will just add one general loop task, that will loop through all log files and delete those that are empty. But still the logic is not clear for me, why in case of failure I still proceed, but seems this is how it works.